# How to install NVS via Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm attempting to install [NVS](https://github.com/jasongin/nvs) via Ansible but not having much luck. Following the [instructions on the repo](https://github.com/jasongin/nvs#mac-linux), it seems that I should first make sure to set the `NVS_HOME` environment variable, then clone the repo, then run the installer.

Thus, here is how I have it set up in my playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  remote_user: "{{ new_user }}"
  gather_facts: true
  environment:
    NVS_HOME: ~/.nvs

  tasks:
    - name: See if NVS is already installed
      lineinfile:
        path: ~/.zshrc
        line: export NVS_HOME="$HOME/.nvs"
        state: present
      check_mode: true
      register: zshrc

    - name: Clone the NVS repo
      git:
        repo: https://github.com/jasongin/nvs
        dest: "$NVS_HOME"
        version: v1.6.0
      ignore_errors: true
      when: (zshrc is changed) or (zshrc is failed)

    - name: Ensure NVS is installed
      shell: ". \"$NVS_HOME/nvs.sh\" install"
      when: (zshrc is changed) or (zshrc is failed)
```

With this, it first checks to see if NVS is installed and won't bother with the following two tasks if it is. Cloning is not a problem, so that leaves the final step of installing.

When Ansible gets to the final task, it outputs an error. Here's the result of that task from the Ansible debugger:

```sh
[localhost] TASK: Ensure NVS is installed (debug)> p result._result

{'_ansible_no_log': False,
 '_ansible_parsed': True,
 'changed': True,
 'cmd': '. "$NVS_HOME/nvs.sh" install',
 'delta': '0:00:00.002482',
 'end': '2020-11-24 12:53:52.983307',
 'failed': True,
 'invocation': {'module_args': {'_raw_params': '. "$NVS_HOME/nvs.sh" install',
                                '_uses_shell': True,
                                'argv': None,
                                'chdir': None,
                                'creates': None,
                                'executable': None,
                                'removes': None,
                                'stdin': None,
                                'stdin_add_newline': True,
                                'strip_empty_ends': True,
                                'warn': True}},
 'msg': 'non-zero return code',
 'rc': 127,
 'start': '2020-11-24 12:53:52.980825',
 'stderr': "/bin/sh: 1: .: Can't open ~/.nvs/nvs.sh",
 'stderr_lines': ["/bin/sh: 1: .: Can't open ~/.nvs/nvs.sh"],
 'stdout': '',
 'stdout_lines': []}
```

So I don't know what to do at this point. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your `dest: "$NVS_HOME"` in git task.
I suggest to declare a variable and use it in your environment and in your task

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: "{{ new_user }}"
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
      nvs_home: "~/.nvs"
  environment:
     NVS_HOME: "{{ nvs_home }}"
```

And in your git task:

```
- name: Clone the NVS repo
  git:
    repo: https://github.com/jasongin/nvs
    dest: "{{ nvs_home }}"
    version: v1.6.0
  ignore_errors: true
  when: (zshrc is changed) or (zshrc is failed)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, sadok. However, I'm afraid that results in the exact same error. I've amended the original question to show the expanded output from that task.

Comment: How about changing your install task to `shell: "export NVS_HOME=\"$HOME/.nvs\" && . {{ nvs_home }}/nvs.sh install"`

Comment: Still fails. No error message, but it spits out a return code of "2."